# Python: How to get these lists transformed in a dictionary?

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have a little creative Python problem. I can't come up with an elegant and preferable short way to write this.

I have 4 lists, 3 of them have 1 element, the 4th might have more (might also be one).

I need a script that transforms these 4 lists to a series of specific formatted dictionary. I'll give a few examples what I want to do

For instance:

```
W=['spaghetti']
X=['banana']
Y=['tomato']
Z=['lemonade', 'milk']
```

I need this:

```
dict1 = {'fruit':'banana' , 'food':'spaghetti' , 'vegetable':'tomato' , 'drink':'lemonade'}
dict2 = {'fruit':'banana' , 'food':'spaghetti' , 'vegetable':'tomato' , 'drink':'milk'}
```

But it can also be 3 or more elements:

```
W=['spaghetti']
X=['banana']
Y=['tomato']
Z=['lemonade', 'milk', 'water']
```

For these, the results should be:

```
 dict1 = {'fruit':'banana' , 'food':'spaghetti' , 'vegetable':'tomato' , 'drink':'lemonade'}
 dict2 = {'fruit':'banana' , 'food':'spaghetti' , 'vegetable':'tomato' , 'drink':'milk'}
 dict3 = {'fruit':'banana' , 'food':'spaghetti' , 'vegetable':'tomato' , 'drink':'water'}
```

Also, another list than Z can be the more than 1 element list:

```
W=['spaghetti']
X=['banana', 'apple']
Y=['tomato']
Z=['lemonade']
```

In this case, I need:

```
dict1 = {'fruit':'banana' , 'food':'spaghetti' , 'vegetable':'tomato' , 'drink':'lemonade'}
dict2 = {'fruit':'apple' , 'food':'spaghetti' , 'vegetable':'tomato' , 'drink':'lemonade'}
```

So basically:

- Given:

  - 3 1-element lists
  - 1 n-element list
- Result:

  - n dictioraries with 4 key - value pairs: 1 key-value pair form each list
  - Same dict value for key corresponding to 1-element lists
  - Different dict value for key corresponding to n-element list

Comment: have you tried anything yourself?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, you are taking the [Cartesian product](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_product) of the lists, and making a dictionary from each result. Since you don't know ahead of time how many results there will be, you cannot just assign to `dict1`, `dict2` etc. (Besides, it should already be evident that this is a silly idea from the names you're using. After all, you did not write `Z1 = 'lemonade'`; `Z2 = 'milk'` etc. Think carefully about why not.) Instead, we shall make a `list` of those results.

So we want a `list` consisting of (some `dict` that can be expressed in terms of a `tuple`), for each `tuple` that we get by taking the Cartesian product. Fortunately, "taking the Cartesian product" is built in to the standard library, which lets us write a single expression (not counting the import ;) ) that means exactly what it says (first sentence of this paragraph):

```
from itertools import product
# define W, X, Y, Z...
menus = [
    {'fruit': fruit, 'food': food, 'vegetable': vegetable, 'drink': drink}
    for fruit, food, vegetable, drink in product(W, X, Y, Z)
]
```

This approach allows any of the source lists to contain multiple elements (or no elements ;) ) with no necessary modification.

Comment: I am getting the following result using this approach, it appears to be mixed up.. what's going wrong? [{'food': 'Banana', 'vegetable': 'tomato', 'fruit': 'spaghetti', 'drink': 'lemonade'}, {'food': 'Banana', 'vegetable': 'tomato', 'fruit': 'spaghetti', 'drink': 'milk'}] I defined W, X, Y, Z as above..

Comment: I got it, just a heads up that in order for this to work W must equal the fruit and X the food

Comment: Well, using more descriptive names than `W, X, Y, Z`  is probably a good idea anyway ;)

Comment: Fantastic Karl!! I had a feeling Python could do this fairly easy but didn't knew how.
The reason I use lists for V,X,Y,Z is because I don't know upfront which of the 4 categories will have more than one value. So a list seemed a good idea. 'Think carefully about why not' How could I do this in a better way? Always eager to imporve...
BTW, this was just a simplified example; I didn't want to complicate the question by using the actual data types. Thanks a bunch!!!

Comment: You *are supposed to* use lists for what you currently call `W` etc. The point was that, *because of the same reasons that you already understand*, you should *also* use a list to store the output results (and not `dict1`, `dict2` etc.).